# Can't determine what is causing a segmentation fault

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, segmentation-fault, gdb

I have a python script (2.7) that implements some C libraries (Numpy and Sklearn). In it I build an array using numpy and then input the array into Sklearn. The program itself works without a flaw when an array is built from a tab delimited file with 29,000 identifiers and 20 representative numbers per identifier.

When I go to run it on something bigger though (in this case something wth 89,000) identifiers the program produces a segmentation fault (core dumped).

The error occurs after Numpy builds the array when it goes to input the array into SKlearn. 
**UPDATE**

I ran GDB (and a bt as suggested) on it and all it did was print out this after getting through building the array.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
0x00007ffff5e755c8 in ATL_dgezero () from /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
```

bt

```
#0  0x00007ffff5e755c8 in ATL_dgezero () from /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
#1  0x00007ffff5e9b09f in ATL_dprk_kmm () from /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
#2  0x00007ffff5ea71a5 in ATL_dsprk_rK () from /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
#3  0x00007ffff5eaaf43 in ATL_dsyrk () from /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
#4  0x00007ffff62fa063 in syrk (typenum=typenum@entry=12,    trans=trans@entry=CblasNoTrans, n=84936, k=<optimized out>, A=A@entry=0x7fffd3371c10, lda=<optimized out>, R=0x7fffd3371a80, order=CblasRowMajor) at numpy/core/src/multiarray/cblasfuncs.c:131
#5  0x00007ffff63db162 in cblas_matrixproduct (typenum=typenum@entry=12, ap1=ap1@entry=0x7fffd3371c10, ap2=ap2@entry=0x7fffd3371940, out=out@entry=0x0)
at numpy/core/src/multiarray/cblasfuncs.c:729
#6  0x00007ffff63b01f4 in PyArray_MatrixProduct2 (op1=<optimized out>, op2=0x7fffd3371940, out=0x0) at numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c:938
#7  0x00007ffff63b0caa in array_matrixproduct (__NPY_UNUSED_TAGGEDdummy=   <optimized out>, args=0x7fffd3376d40, kwds=0x0)
at numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c:2186
#8  0x000000000052c6d5 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () 
#9  0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#10 0x000000000052ca8d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#11 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#12 0x000000000052ca8d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#13 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#14 0x000000000052ca8d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () 
#15 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#16 0x000000000052ca8d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#17 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#18 0x000000000052ca8d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#19 0x000000000055c594 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#20 0x00000000005b7392 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#21 0x0000000000469663 in ?? ()
#22 0x00000000004699e3 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#23 0x0000000000469f1c in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#24 0x000000000046ab81 in Py_Main ()
#25 0x00007ffff7818ec5 in __libc_start_main (main=0x46ac3f <main>, argc=16,     argv=0x7fffffffe298, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>,
rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe288) at libc-start.c:287
#26 0x000000000057497e in _start ()
```

`

I can't figure out if  this is a memory issue since it works perfectly fine with small input files, or if it is something in the code that refuses to handle huge datasets.

Any suggestions on another way to trouble shoot or why this might be happening?

**UPDATE**
Finished running `strace` and got this at the end of the output when it failed

```
.......
brk(0x7a71000)                          = 0x7a71000
read(4, "TAC\nACTCAACCTTTGGGCGGAAAAGGTTAGC"..., 4096) = 4096
brk(0x8384000)                          = 0x8384000
read(4, "GTCTTCTAATGAACTAAACT\nTATCGATGATA"..., 4096) = 3675
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
brk(0x715f000)                          = 0x715f000
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7ff031ad5000, 4096)            = 0
write(1, "(84936, 14)\n", 12(84936, 14)
)           = 12
munmap(0x7ff01458b000, 12587008)        = 0
write(1, "\n        \n        \n        -----"..., 203


    -------------------------------------------------------
                  ---array finished---
    -------------------------------------------------------

) = 203
write(1, "        \n", 9
)               = 9
mmap(NULL, 57712996352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1,       0) = 0x7fe29cce2000
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x7fde9df831c8} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

ulimit -d 
unlimited
```

**UPDATE**
 free -h to look at the memory gave this:

```
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1.0T       973G        34G        17M       257M       743G
-/+ buffers/cache:       230G       777G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Comment: Is that the only error that is output, meaning nothing else whatsoever?

Comment: Yes, that's all it outputs other than printing out the messages prior that I put in the script to say "coverage array being built" and 'coverage array finished" I can also see the array shape being printing out so I know it is finishing the module built to get the array.

Comment: Are you running this on a linux machine? If so you might want to try `strace python ...` or execute the script within a debugger (eg. `gdb`, `lldb`, etc.) that way you might have a better idea of where the problem originates. It could be a bug in the library, or something else altogether...

Comment: It is on a linux machine, I will try strace and lldb and see if that works, gdb is what I already tried and didn't give me a ton of information.

Comment: It may help if you provide a backtrace (e.g., type in "bt" at the GDB prompt, after the segfault occurs).

Comment: It might very well be a 'size' issue, or a bug by looking at value of the mmap length (57712996352) — seems possible at least; if you don't have that much available space to privately map then that could cause it.

Comment: That mmap is clearly the issue. 57gb is certainly a corrupt allocation size.  Can you post some source code?  Either the memory growth of the program is exploding or there is a bug in the memory handling.

Comment: The source is from a github program >https://github.com/edgraham/BinSanity/                                                          I was told the program used a lot of memory, but I also know someone who ran it on a comparable sized dataset, but I think they said it used about 200 gb of memory. The server I am running on is a shared server and should have 1 tb of memory.

Comment: Can you show the output of `ulimit -d` ? There are configurable per-process limits which can be tighter than hard limits like RAM and swap space.

Comment: It said unlimited when I did ulimit -d, but last time I did this (e.g yesterday) that is not what it said... I am going to test it to see if the segfault happens again though.